# smallest multiple javascript

Tags: javascript, lcm

I have to find the lcm of all the numbers 1 through and including 20, and I came up with this code.  It, although is inefficient and also comes up with an answer that is 2 more than the correct answer. Could anyone tell me why?

```
//variable used to shut off the while loop.
divisable = false;

var i = 2;

//function to prove if the number is a lcm

var isDivisable = function(number){
    for(var i = 2; i<=20; i++){
        if(number%i !== 0){
            divisable = false;
            //  added the break to shut down the function, 
            //  as no other loops need to be counted
            break;
        }else{
            divisable = true;
        }
    }
};    


while(!divisable){
    isDivisable(i);

    i+=2;
}
```

Comment: You cannot say `var i = 2` if you define it in your loop

Comment: right, I'm sorry I used j instead of i, just didn't transfer it over to this.  Look at it as if that is not a problem.

Comment: LCM(a, b) = (a * b) / GCD(a, b)

Comment: `answer that is 2 more than the correct answer`: The line `i+=2` might have something to do with that! After you call `isDivisable` you are incrementing `i` again before you test the loop condition to see if you should quit. I'd reverse those two lines and start `i` at `0` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What was wrong with my code?

`isDivisible` keeps executing until `divisible` is set to true (from your **while** loop), where your `for` loop will do all that for you.  Also, you're putting `i+=2` in the while loop, which adds 2 to the result, after your program stops spazzing out from executing `isDivisible` so many times.

### How to fix?

Remove the **while** loop, and just call `isDivisable` manually.

```
var isDivisable = function(number){
    if (number % 1 == 0) {
    for(var i = 2; i<=20; i++){
        if(number%i !== 0){
            divisable = false;
            //  added the break to shut down the function, 
            //  as no other loops need to be counted
            break;
        }else{
            divisable = true;
            alert(i);
        }
    }else
    {
        alert('Your number is not divisible.');
    }
};    

isDivisable(6); //Replace with a number
```

The result is that `i` will be the multiple.

### Additional Notes

`isDivisible` is spelled wrong in your code, as `isDivisable`.

Comment: I wonder if you need a loop to know if the value is devisible by these values?

Answer (score 0):

For fun:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map(function(i) {
    if(this % i == 0)
        alert(i);
}, 6);
```

Should `alert` when the value contained in the array (`[0, . . ., 6]`) is a multiple of the value passed to the callback (in this case `6`). See [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

http://jsfiddle.net/5nSE4/1/